# Symfony how to change user password with SonataAdmin?

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I have an Admin class for sign into administrator page, It is implements `UserInterface`:

```
**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\AdminRepository")
 */
class Admin implements UserInterface
{
...
}
```

It is an entity as a user provider in security.yaml:

```
security:
    providers:
        app_user_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\Admin
                property: username
```

This admin provider is used for sign into SonataAdmin page without using FOSUserBundle

And I created a `AdminAdmin` class for update/create admin users in SonataAdmin:

```
final class AdminAdmin extends AbstractAdmin
{

}
```

But there is no tutorials about how to update user password in the SonataAdmin, So I decided to change the `setPassword` in Admin entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\AdminRepository")
 */
class Admin implements UserInterface

{
    public function __construct(UserPasswordEncoderInterface $passwordEncoder)
    {
        $this->passwordEncoder = $passwordEncoder;
    }

    public function setPassword(string $password): self
    {
        dd($this->passwordEncoder);
        $this->password = $this->passwordEncoder->encodePassword($this, $password);

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Looks above, I tried to use UserPasswordEncoderInterface for encode password, but the problem is that `passwordEncoder` is null, the UserPasswordEncoderInterface service cannot be inject to the Admin entity.

So what is the proper way to update user password with SonataAdmin

Comment: Have same issue now, hope you will find solution.

Comment: Please check the new answer

Answer (score 1):

I found a hack way:

create a AdminAdminController extends CRUDController,

```
final class AdminAdminController extends CRUDController
{
    /**
     * @var UserPasswordEncoderInterface
     */
    private $passwordEncode;

    public function __construct(UserPasswordEncoderInterface $passwordEncode)
    {
        $this->passwordEncode = $passwordEncode;
    }


    public function editAction($id = null)
    {
        $existingObject = $this->admin->getObject($id);

        $uniqid = $this->getRequest()->query->get('uniqid');
        $formData = $this->getRequest()->request->get($uniqid);

        if ($formData['password']['first'] ===  $formData['password']['second']){
            $enPass = $this->passwordEncode->encodePassword($existingObject, $formData['password']['first']);
            $formData['password'] = [
                'first' => $enPass,
                'second' => $enPass
            ];
            $this->getRequest()->request->set($uniqid, $formData);
            return parent::editAction($id);
        }else{
            return parent::editAction($id);
        }
    }
```

But I still wanna to know how to change user password in the entity, it is simple and DRY.

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, an entity should never have a dependency, so you need to remove the dependency injection in your entity.

In your `AdminAdmin` (confusing name) you need to add the password field like so:

```php
->add('plainPassword', RepeatedType::class, [
    'type' => PasswordType::class,
    'options' => [
        'translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle',
    ],
    'first_options' => ['label' => 'form.password'],
    'second_options' => ['label' => 'form.password_confirmation'],
    'invalid_message' => 'fos_user.password.mismatch',
    'required' => true,
])
```

You'll need to dependency inject the `UserManager` into your admin class, like the following:

```php
private $userManager;

public function __construct($code, $class, $baseControllerName, UserManagerInterface $userManager)
{
    $this->userManager = $userManager;

    parent::__construct($code, $class, $baseControllerName);
}
```

This may error because it cannot autowire the dependency, add this line to your `admin.yaml` under your admin definition: `autowire: true`.

Finally add the `preUpdate()` method to your admin class with the following:

```php
public function preUpdate($object)
{
    parent::preUpdate($object);

    if ($object->getPlainPassword()) {
        $this->userManager->updatePassword($object);
    }
}
```

That should now update the password correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, But i am not using FOSUserBundle for SonataAdmin